# Sybase: FOR BROWSE and ORDER BY

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have table with primary key "id" (in test table id from 2 to 5). If I using query like

```
 select * from sometable order by id DESC
```

result sorted as expected from 5 to 2. But if I add FOR BROWSE like

```
select * from sometable order by id DESC FOR BROWSE
```

result sorted from 2 to 5. I checked that also in Interactive SQL.

Is it possible to get proper DESC order with FOR BROWSE? Because FOR BROWSE crucial for me: with direct access to server without drivers it sends TDS_COLINFO (table names by fields, also can be retrieved from TDS_ROWFMT2) token and proper flags for key fields (also can be retrieved as meta table info, but requires additional requests from server I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: Just FYI, Sybase/SAP recommends against using it - http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32840.1570/html/ctref/X24200.htm

Comment: Those info about browse mode and their libs. Since I'm using TDS protocol I don't care about libs and how bad they are at using it. And "browse mode is Sybase-specific" isn't true, Sql Server also uses browse mode through "SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON" (or OFF). Both old Sybase/TDS based but I must admit in Sql Server it works better and without SQL modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SAP support:

> This is a known defect, CR 710333, no estimate for when it will be fixed.

It seems bug reported since ASE 15.7.